# rake routes action controller info missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

well i've been following lectures and im not sure if this is the wrong place if it is sorry.

but when i run

```
rake routes
```

using ruby on rails i get

```
   movies GET    /movies(.:format)          movies#index
           POST   /movies(.:format)          movies#create
 new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)      movies#new
edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format) movies#edit
     movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)      movies#show
           PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)      movies#update
           DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)      movies#destroy
      root        /                          :controller#:action
```

now the videos i've been following they get

```
    movies GET    /movies(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"movies"}
           POST   /movies(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"movies"}
 new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"movies"}
edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"movies"}
     movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"movies"}
           PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"movies"}
           DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"movies"}
      root        /                          {:to=>#<Proc:0x8c93620@/usr/local/lib/ruby/gem   k-3.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/redirection.rb:87 {labda}>)
```

how do i get it to do display the action controller like that its alot easie to read compared to how it is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally find the standard output (the first output, in your case) better to read and decipher.

The latter output you shown was probably used in Rails versions < 3.2, if I recall correctly; so, it is probable that the tutorial you are following is using one of those versions of Rails.

I will suggest you to look at [**color_routes**](https://github.com/nicooga/color_routes) gem. It shows your routes in pretty good fashion -

[image: Image from the page]

Answer (score 1):

it is displaying the controller and the action just in a different formatted way

movies#show -> controller is movies and show is the action

I would check the version on rails being used in video and the version that you are using